# Mask data in Mongoose find operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The requirement is to mask mobile number and show only last 4 digits. I do not want this to be performed at client instead mask it before sending the response. I am not sure how to modify transaction object to mask the data. I want to check if there is any mongoose function to do this. If not please suggest me the best way to mask a selected field.

Logic to fetch transactions

```
Transaction.find(query).populate('from','name mobile email').sort({ createdAt : -1 }).skip((page) * limit).limit(limit).exec((err, transaction) =>{
            if(transaction){
                Transaction.countDocuments({to:id,paymentStatus:"SUCCESS"},function(err,count){
                    return res.status(200).send({transaction,count:count});
                });
            }
            else if(transaction==null) return res.status(200).send("No Transactions Found");
            else if(err) return res.status(400).send("Error Occurred");
     });
```

User.Model.ts - Merchant model is similar with some additional fields

```
var User= new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type:String,required:"E-Mail address cannot be empty",unique:true},
    mobile:{type:String,required:"Mobile number cannot be empty",min : [10,"Please provide a valid 10 digit mobile number"],unique:true},
    password:{type:String,required:"Password cannot be empty",minlength : [4,"Password must be more than 4 characters"]},
   .......some unrelated fields...
});
```

Transaction.Model.ts

```
var transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    from:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    amount : {type:String,required:true},
    to:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Merchant'  },
    paymentStatus:{type : String, default : "INCOMPLETE"},
     .......some unrelated fields...
});
```

Current output

```
{"transaction":[{"paymentStatus":"SUCCESS","isDisputed":true,"_id":"5eb8e50b3e2adb3b74e85d4f","from":{"_id":"5eb8e50a3e2adb3b74e85d43","name":"John Doe","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"9999999999"},"amount":"40","to":"5eb8e50a3e2adb3b74e85d46"}],"count":1}
```

Expected output

```
{"transaction":[{"paymentStatus":"SUCCESS","isDisputed":true,"_id":"5eb8e50b3e2adb3b74e85d4f","from":{"_id":"5eb8e50a3e2adb3b74e85d43","name":"John Doe","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"*******999"},"amount":"40","to":"5eb8e50a3e2adb3b74e85d46"}],"count":1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string-masking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-masking) to mask the fields after you fetch them.
Mongoose plugin, virtuals or getters would also involve you to iterate over the array so the end result is same.

```
let stringMasking = require('string-masking');
...
transactions = transactions.map(transaction => {
    let mask = stringMasking(transaction.from.phone, 0);
    transaction.from.phone = mask.response;
    return transaction;
});
...
return res.status(200).send({transaction,count:transaction.length});
```

Also its better to make the password not included in all find queries if not needed. Can be done by :

```
 password: {type: String,select: false}
```